org.springframework.web.client.UnknownContentTypeException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for responsetype
org.springframework.web.client.UnknownContentTypeException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class java.lang.Integer] and content type [text/plain;charset=UTF-8]
Im getting above error for below method in QuestionController Service Class
QuizController.java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("quiz")
public class QuizController {
@Autowired
QuizService quizservice;

// Create quiz for admin
@PostMapping("createquiz")
public Object createQuiz(@RequestBody QuizDto quizDto)
{
    return quizservice.createQuiz(quizDto);
}

// Get questions from given quiz Id for users
@GetMapping("getquestions/{quizId}")
public Object getQuestionsFromQuizIds(@PathVariable Integer quizId)
{
    return quizservice.getQuestionsFromQuizId(quizId);
}

// Calculaet score of user as per user's response-
@PostMapping("claculateScore")
public Object claculateScore(@RequestBody List<Response> responses)
{
    return quizservice.claculateScore(responses);
}

@PostMapping("getScore")
public Object getScoreForUsers(@RequestBody List<Response> responses)
{
    return quizservice.getScoreForUsers(responses);
}

}

QuizService.java
@Service
public class QuizService {

    @Autowired
    QuizInterface quizInterface;

    @Autowired
    QuizRepo quizRepo;

    public Object createQuiz(QuizDto quizDto) {
        try {
            if (quizDto.getTitle() != null && quizDto.getCategory() != null && quizDto.getNumOfQues() != null) {
                Quiz quiz = new Quiz();
                quiz.setTitlel(quizDto.getTitle());
                List<Integer> questionIds = quizInterface.findQuestionIdsForUsers(quizDto.getCategory(),
                        quizDto.getNumOfQues());
                quiz.setQuestionIds(questionIds);
                quizRepo.save(quiz);
                return new ResponseEntity<>("Quiz Saved in DB successfully...", HttpStatus.OK);
            } else {
                return new ResponseEntity<>("title, category or numOfQuestions is never passed in request...",
                        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

    }

    // This function is dependent on both quiz and question DB
    public Object getQuestionsFromQuizId(Integer quizId) {
        System.out.println("Reaching quiz service.....................................******************&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&");
        try {
            Optional<Quiz> quiz_optional = quizRepo.findById(quizId);
            if(!quiz_optional.isPresent())
                return new ResponseEntity<>("Requested quizId is not present in DB", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            Quiz quiz = quiz_optional.get();
            System.out.println(quiz.toString());                                /////////////////////////////****************************************************** */
            List<Integer> questionIds = quiz.getQuestionIds();
            System.out.println("Before interface............................******************&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&");
            List<QuestionOnly> questionsFromQuestionIdsforUsers = quizInterface
                    .findQuestionsFromQuestionIds(questionIds);
            System.out.println(questionsFromQuestionIdsforUsers.toString());    /////////////////////////////****************************************************** */
            return new ResponseEntity<>(questionsFromQuestionIdsforUsers, HttpStatus.OK);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Couldn't create questions"+e.getMessage(),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    public Object claculateScore(List<Response> responses) {
        System.out.println(
                "Reaching calculate score..................score.................score.score.................score.score.................score.score.................score");
        System.out.println("Here its in quiz service " + quizInterface.claculateScore(responses));
        return quizInterface.claculateScore(responses);
    }
    
    public Object getScoreForUsers(List<Response> responses) {
        Object score = quizInterface.getScoreForUsers(responses);
        return score;
    }

}

QuizInterface
@FeignClient("QUESTION-SERVICE")
public interface QuizInterface {
    @GetMapping("question/createQuestionsForUsers")
    public List<Integer> findQuestionIdsForUsers(@RequestParam String category, @RequestParam Integer numOfQues); // Here the function declaration should be like just how its present in QuestionService.

    @PostMapping("question/getQuestionsFromquestionIds")
    public List<QuestionOnly> findQuestionsFromQuestionIds(@RequestBody List<Integer> questionIds);

    @PostMapping("question/claculateScore")
    public Object claculateScore(@RequestBody List<Response> responses);

    @PostMapping("question/getScore")
    public Object getScoreForUsers(@RequestBody List<Response> responses);
    
}

QuestionController
@RestController
@RequestMapping("question")
public class QuestionController {
    @Autowired
    QuestionService questionService;

    // Create
    @PostMapping("addAllQuestions")
    public Object addAllQuestions(@RequestBody List<Question> questions)
    {
        return questionService.addAllQuestions(questions);
    }

    //Read
    @GetMapping("viewAllQuestions")
    public Object viewAllQuestions()
    {
        return questionService.viewAllQuestions();
    }

    // Update
    @PutMapping("updateQuestion")
    public Object updateQuestions(@RequestBody Question question)
    {
        return questionService.updateQuestions(question);
    }

    // Delete
    @DeleteMapping("deleteQuestion")
    public Object deleteQuestion(@RequestParam Integer id)
    {
        return questionService.deleteQuestion(id);
    }

    // Methods for quiz - 
    @GetMapping("createQuestionsForUsers")
    public List<Integer> findQuestionIdsForUsers(@RequestParam String category,@RequestParam Integer numOfQues)
    {
        return questionService.findQuestionIdsForUsers(category, numOfQues);
    }

    @PostMapping("getQuestionsFromquestionIds")
    public Object findQuestionsFromQuestionIds(@RequestBody List<Integer> questionIds) {
        System.out.println("Reaching question controller..........");
        return questionService.findQuestionsFromQuestionIds(questionIds);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("claculateScore")
    public Object claculateScore(@RequestBody List<Response> responses)
    {
        System.out.println(
                "reaching claculate score questionoo9oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo");////////////////////////////=====================================
        System.out.println("Hereit is - " + questionService.claculateScore(responses));
        return questionService.claculateScore(responses);
    }

    @PostMapping("getScore")
    public Object getScoreForUsers(@RequestBody List<Response> responses)
    {
        return questionService.getScoreForUsers(responses);
    }
}

QuestionService
@Service
public class QuestionService {

    @Autowired
    QuestionRepo questionRepo;
    public Object addAllQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
        if(!questions.isEmpty())
        {
            questionRepo.saveAll(questions);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(questions.size()+" questions added to DB", HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("No questions found for adding to DB....", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    public Object viewAllQuestions() {
        try {
            List<Question> questions = questionRepo.findAll();
            if (questions.isEmpty()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>("Cannot find any question to view inside DB...", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            } 
            else
                return new ResponseEntity<>(questions, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    public Object updateQuestions(Question question) {
        try {
            Optional<Question> questionToBeUpdated_optional = questionRepo.findById(question.getId());  // This statement will throw an exception here.
            if(questionToBeUpdated_optional.isPresent())
            {
                Question updatedQuestion = new Question(question.getId(), question.getQuestionTitle(),
                        question.getOption1(), question.getOption2(), question.getOption3(), question.getOption4(),
                        question.getRightAnswer(), question.getDifficultylevel(), question.getCategory());
                questionRepo.save(updatedQuestion);
                return new ResponseEntity<>("Updated question is - "+ questionRepo.findById(question.getId()).toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                return new ResponseEntity<>("Question to be updated is not present in DB", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Please provide a question with ID.",HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    public Object deleteQuestion(Integer id) {
        try {
            Integer idToBeDeleted = id;
            if (questionRepo.existsById(id))
                questionRepo.deleteById(idToBeDeleted); // deleteById will not throw exception even if idToBeDeleted is null.
            else
                return new ResponseEntity<>("Question with provided id is not present in DB", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Question Deleted SuccessFully....", HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Please enter a question Id which need to be deleted...",
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    // Methods used in Quiz interface - 
    
    public List<Integer> findQuestionIdsForUsers(String category, Integer numOfQues) {
        return questionRepo.findQuestionIdsForUsers(category, numOfQues);
    }

    // public List<QuestionOnly> findQuestionsFromQuestionIds(List<Integer> questionIds) {
    //     System.out.println("Reaching question service..........");
    //     List<QuestionOnly> questionsForUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    //     for(Integer questionId : questionIds)
    //     {
    //         Question questionForQuestionId = questionRepo.findById(questionId).get();
    //         questionsForUsers.add(new QuestionOnly(questionForQuestionId.getId(), questionForQuestionId.getQuestionTitle(),
    //                         questionForQuestionId.getOption1(), questionForQuestionId.getOption2(),
    //                         questionForQuestionId.getOption3(), questionForQuestionId.getOption4()));
    //     }
    //     return questionsForUsers;
    // }

    public Object findQuestionsFromQuestionIds(List<Integer> questionIds) {
        System.out.println("Reaching question service..........");
        List<QuestionOnly> questionsForUsers = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Integer questionId : questionIds)
        {
            Question questionForQuestionId = questionRepo.findById(questionId).get();
            questionsForUsers.add(new QuestionOnly(questionForQuestionId.getId(), questionForQuestionId.getQuestionTitle(),
                            questionForQuestionId.getOption1(), questionForQuestionId.getOption2(),
                            questionForQuestionId.getOption3(), questionForQuestionId.getOption4()));
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(questionsForUsers.toString(),HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    public Object claculateScore(List<Response> responses) {
        System.out.println("Reaching claculateScore questionService......................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&********************************(((((((((((((((())))))))))))))))");
        try {
            if (responses.isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println("Testing......................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&********************************(((((((((((((((())))))))))))))))");
                return new ResponseEntity<>("please choose any answer and submit..", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
            Integer score = 0;
            for (Response response : responses) {
                String rightAnswer = questionRepo.findById(response.getId()).get().getRightAnswer();

                if (response.getChosenAnswer().equals(rightAnswer))
                    score++;
            }
            String res = "Your score is - ";
            return new ResponseEntity<>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public Object getScoreForUsers(List<Response> responses)
    {
        try {
            if (!responses.isEmpty()) {
                Integer score = 0;
                for(Response r:responses)
                {
                    Optional<Question> questionOptional = questionRepo.findById(r.getId());
                    if (questionOptional.isPresent()) {
                        Question question = questionOptional.get();
                        if (question.getRightAnswer().equals(r.getChosenAnswer()))
                            score++;
                    } 
                    else {
                        throw new NullPointerException("Question with requested ID - " + r.getId() + " is not present in DB");
                    }
                }
                return new ResponseEntity<>(score, HttpStatus.OK);    // -This line is working
                // return new ResponseEntity<>("Your score is = "+score, HttpStatus.OK); // But this line is not working - here I am getting - " no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type" error why is that?
            } else {
                return new ResponseEntity<>("No options selected....",HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
    
}


This method returns a String, could it be that your API method defines an Integer ResponseEntity type?

Hi @EdmarSM I have added the codes for API methods also here, can you please check what is the cause of this issue.
Thanks...

Are you receiving the error in this app itself or another app consuming this method?

Hi @EdmarSM,
In this app itself.
